# Create matrix: first n rows, 1st column has 1s and all other columns 0s, the next n rows, 2nd column has 1s and all other columns 0s and so forth

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to generate a matrix where in the first n rows, the first column has 1s and all other columns have 0s. In the next n rows, the second column has 1s and all other columns have 0s and so forth. For example, when n=2 and the number of columns is 3 then the matrix would look like this

A =

```
 1 0 0 
 1 0 0 
 0 1 0 
 0 1 0 
 0 0 1
 0 0 1
```

If m is the number of columns I used  `kron(eye(m),ones(n,1))`. Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: how do you define `better`?

Comment: What's wrong with your way?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong. I'll change to other ways. What I intended was the fastest way / uses least amount of memory / is my way a god way.

Comment: Faster and less memory are normally not mutually exclusive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what "better" means but here are some alternatives to `kron(eye(m),ones(n,1))`:

```
reshape(repmat(permute(eye(m),[3,2,1]),n,1),[],m)
```

or

```
reshape(bsxfun(@times,ones(n,1),permute(eye(m),[3,2,1])),[],m)
```

or

```
reshape(meshgrid(eye(m),ones(n,1)),[],m)
```

or

```
I = eye(m);
I(ceil((1:m*n)./n),:)
```

or

```
N = n*m;
z = zeros(N,m);
z(sub2ind([N,m],1:N,ceil((1:N)./n))) = 1
```

or

```
C = mat2cell(ones(n,m),n,ones(1,m));
blkdiag(C{:})
```

You can compare the speed using the `timeit` function

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use `permute` in the first solution? My understanding of permute is that it changes the order of the columns so that the third column will be first in this instance. Wouldn't the use of permute here just change the "slope" of the diagonal from a positive to a negative? And why would you use `[3 2 1]` when the matrix is 2D? Don't take it the wrong way but I am just trying to understand...

Comment: `permute` doesn't rearrange the columns, it switches dimensions (almost like a n-d analogue of transposition). So calling `permute` with `[3,2,1]` on a 2d matrix makes it a 3d matrix with one row

Comment: I tried the first solution and it works with `m=5,n=3` but not with `m=5,n=2`. `error: reshape: SIZE is not divisible by the product of known dimensions (= 3)`. Is there a way to make it work for `n=2`?

Comment: @kkuilla yes sorry I left a `3` in there that should be an `m`. See the edit